# Как поступать с огромными данными, которые часто используются?

Tags: база-данных

На примерах возьмем файлы, допустим видео, длинной > 30mb (их будет очень много, как в видеоресурсах), а также лайки к этим видео.

Как стоит манипулировать этими данными, какие базы данных использовать, как кэшировать?

В случае лайков лучше использовать Redis, Memcached, или MongoDB?

На примере лайков > 1,000,000,000; видеофайлов > 10000.

Comment: Большие файлы обычно всё же хранят в файловой системе, а в БД хранят пути к этим файлам. Если хотите хранить такие объёмные файлы именно в БД, это придётся какую-то промышленную БД использовать. А лайки у вас именные или просто количество? Количество хранить не проблема, хоть сколько - это же просто значение счётчика.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за ответ. Насчет лайков, хранится не количество, а связка id пользователя с id видео. (чтобы например когда он зашел на видео, было отображено что лайк поставлен)

Comment: Если нормально индексировать таблицу, это не проблема выбрать лайки по пользователю, вопрос в том, сколько пользователей одновременно ходит в базу, если очень много, то тут и могут начаться проблемы. Надо пробовать на какой-то конфигурации и смотреть. Заранее думаю вам вряд ли кто точно скажет под ваши конкретно условия что подойдёт.